# What is the Russian equivalent for "circa"?

Tags: сокращения

It's clear enough that something like "1993 г." designates a precise year, but in English one can write "c. 1993" (i.e. "circa 1993"), indicating that the exact year is unknown. Is there an equivalent in Russian? It feels awkward to write "около 1993 г."

Comment: В разговорной речи часто применяется такая необычная конструкция: *"году в девяносто третьем"*.

Comment: около is totally OK. Why awkward?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This form is ok when there's no conflicting government:

> Около 1804 года в Смоленской губернии, верстах в двадцати от города Ельни, проживал в собственном своем имении, селе Новоспасском, отставной капитан Иван Николаевич Глинка.

However, if there's a conflict of government (when adding the preposition *около* would change the noun's case), Rosenthal suggests replacing it with an adverb (Rosenthal et al., №200.4):

> Конструкция может оказаться в двойной зависимости при несочетаемости двух форм управления, например:
>
> > *…потребовал обнародования петиции, подписанной свыше миллиона граждан, выступающих против повышения квартирной платы* (подписанной *кем?* свыше *чего?*; возможный вариант правки: *подписанной свыше чем миллионом граждан*);

> > *В проходе разрешается стоять не свыше 25 экскурсантов* (разрешается *кому?* не свыше  *чего?*;  возможный вариант: *…не больше чем 25 экскурсантам*);

> > *Издание, датируемое около 1600 года* (датируемое *таким-то* годом; около *такого-то* года; возможный вариант: *датируемое приблизительно 1600 годом*).

As an abbreviation, it's widely used in encyclopaedia articles and the like:

> Архимед (Archimedes; ок. 287 — 212 до н. э.), древнегреческий учёный, математик и механик.

Comment: Excellent. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The word "около" (around, near, about) can be abbreviated as "ок."

For example:

> Она родилась ок. 1990 г.